# Fmin python passing parameters

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to find the minimum of the function func_exp.
The function has 3 parameters, which I get from fitting.
Then I want find the minimum value (y) of the function along the x axis. While using the fitted parameters.
For this I'm trying to use fin from scipy

However I seem not really understand how to pass the arguments to the fin function.
with the current code I'm getting  the following error:

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

for any help I be grateful.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import fmin

def func_exp(x,a,b,c):
   return -a*(1-(1-np.exp(-b*(x-c)))**2)

class morse:
    def __init__(self):
        self.masses = {'H': 1, 'D': 2, 'C': 12, 'O': 16}

def exponential_regression (self,x_data, y_data):
    self.popt, pcov = curve_fit(func_exp, x, y, p0 = (0.5, 1.4, 3))
    print(self.popt)
    puntos = plt.plot(x, y, 'x', color='xkcd:maroon', label = "data")
    x_data= np.linspace(np.amax(x),np.amin(x),100)
    curva_regresion = plt.plot(x_data, func_exp(x_data, *self.popt), color='xkcd:teal', label = "fit: {:.3f}, {:.3f}, {:.3f}".format(*self.popt))
    plt.xlim([2, 5.5 ])
    plt.ylim([-5.5, 5 ])
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
    return func_exp(x, *self.popt)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = np.array([2.5,3,3.125,3.25,3.375,3.5,3.625,3.75,4,4.5,5,5.5])
    y = np.array([17.27574826,-3.886390266,-4.892678401,-5.239229709,-5.193942987,-4.93131152,-4.557452444,-4.13446237,-3.276524893,-1.928242445,-1.17731394,-0.745240026])
    morse=morse()
    morse.exponential_regression(x, y)
    fmin(func_exp,x,args=(morse.popt[0],morse.popt[1],morse.popt[2]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. The modification here you have to do is to pass **only one** initial guess value of `x` to `fmin`. You were passing `x` which is of length 12.

Replace

```
fmin(func_exp,x,args=(morse.popt[0],morse.popt[1],morse.popt[2]))
```

by

```
fmin(func_exp,x[0],args=(morse.popt[0],morse.popt[1],morse.popt[2]))
```

where you use only the first element of `x` array as the starting point.

You can also use other values as `x[1]` or `x[-1]` and all will converge to the minimum. The function now will return you the value of `x` for which the curve has a minimum. The answer is

```
array([3.30895996])
```

Comment: I want to numerically get the minimum of the function not to grab the minimum from a list.

Comment: @RaymondGhaffarianShirazi:. I got it. Check my edited answer